# All Font Awesome Icons showing as Shortcode

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome

This is relating to the Wordpress site woodflooringkent.com.

I was attempting to knock off some of the Google Page Speed insight issues, one being the "Ensure text remains visible during webfont load". I added the `font-display: swap;` attribute to the fonts it was pointing out, one of them being `webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2` located within `wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/lib/bower/font-awesome/css/all.min.css`. Upon doing so, I discovered that all FA icons on the site were now displaying as their shortcodes (ie F007 instead of the person icon).

I immediately removed the offending code that I had added and purged the cache from the CDN, but the problem now persists.

Does anyone have any ideas how to reverse my stupidity?

Answer (score 0):

`all.min.css` is a generated source file and should not be edited.

Instead, edit the `CSS` source files `all.min.css` is generated from.

To remove your changes, regenerate `all.min.css` using the tools provided by your theme or page builder.
Judging by the the part of the provided path `wp-content/plugins/js_composer` and after a look at the mentioned website, it looks like that is **WPBakery** in your case.